# Extending properties in Immutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm having this block of code I want to transform into Immutable, and have no idea how I can extend my prop on the immutable object. Can someone show me how? I'm extending the prop, so my immutable object gets the returned result from another module. Currently, also `populateKey` gets set from the outside, and I´ve managed to encapsulate this. Help!! <3 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setIn`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/setIn) method

```
return state.setIn([populateKey, 'type'], result.type).setIn([...])
```

> setIn(keyPath: Array, value: any): Map

Comment: Thanks! Tried it earlier, but it nagged about the type wasn't set!

Comment: I´ll mark as solved in about 10mins btw :) Thanks for the fix yury

Comment: Found out that I've already done that, lol, double work, check

Comment: BTW if you need to run multiple mutations in series take a look at https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/withMutations

Comment: I think Immutable sets it automatically, at least it loops through it.